# leak problem on NSUserDefaults and NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I have a leak in the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
//If Home-Theme
    if (themeIndex == 0) {
        NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSMutableArray *thisArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        thisArray = [[pref objectForKey:@"Themes"] mutableCopy];
        [thisArray release];
    }
}
```

the leak is at NSMutableArray.
I have try'd some different workarounds but nothing is help.
Maybe there is someting wrong with the NSUserDefaults?
any ideas?

thank you
xnz

Comment: Or Ollys as he posted nearly the same thing earlier... @will, you can remind users to accept *an* answer but don't pressure them to accept yours.

Comment: @George Fritszsche - He thanked me in my post... or I wouldnt have. Thanks for policing though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *thisArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

That is leaking since you never release that instance, just assign a new one in the next line. Replace it with:

```
NSMutableArray *thisArray = [[pref objectForKey:@"Themes"] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating a NSMutableArray and the changing the reference to another array.

You probably want something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  //If Home-Theme
  if (themeIndex == 0) {
    NSUserDefaults *pref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *thisArray = [[pref objectForKey:@"Themes"] mutableCopy]];
    // do something with thisArray
    [thisArray release];
  }
}
```

Comment: Your sample is missing a `release`.

Answer (score 0):

you alloc `thisArray` and then overwrite the reference to it with a mutable copy from pref. Either do autorelease or just remove the unnecessary NSMutableArray allocation